# Casting from vector to array of object

Tags: java, xml-rpc

Actually am working on XML-RPC. Am trying to execute a method in client class which returns an array of objects. Here is the way am trying to execute it in client class.

```
Object[] result =  (Object[]) client.execute("getNames" , vector);
```

while vector represent an array of vector of types string & "getNames" represents the methods name in default handler class :

```
public Object[] getNames(String a, String b, String c) {
        Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>();
        strings.add(a);
        strings.add(b);
        strings.add(c);
        String [] arrOfString = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
        return arrOfString ;
    }
```

when running, the following exception occured:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.SimpleClient.<init>(SimpleClient.java:37)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:65)
```

what can I do to solve this casting problem ?

Comment: You call ("getNames",vector) - but your method has signature String,String,String

Comment: I've added 3 strings to Vector<String>.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `toArray` method of the `Vector` class in your `getNames` method.

```
public Object[] getNames(String a, String b, String c) {
        Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>();
        strings.add(a);
        strings.add(b);
        strings.add(c);
        return strings.toArray();
}
```

But, if i get what you really want to do I think you can simply do something like :

```
Object[] result =  vector.toArray();
```

if `vector` is indeed of type `Vector`.

Comment: I tried this solution before but the problem is that execute method take the followig parameter (String, vector), so it doesn't accept vector.toArray().